# Perl - Image::Magick New Image with RGB Background

Tags: perl, imagemagick

I'm trying to create a new image using Image::Magick, and set the background color to an RGB value retrieved from a previous step. However, all that is being written out is a black image.  I know the RGB values are correct, as I verified those.  Below is an example of what I tried.

```
# Read RGB value at pixel 2,11 in another image
my $swatchImg = new Image::Magick;    
$swatchImg->Read($swatchPath)
my @rgb = $swatchImg->GetPixel(x=>2,y=>11); 
undef $swatchImg;   

# Create a new image, with the background set to the rgb value retrieved above 
my $img = Image::Magick->new;
$img->Set(size=>"50x50");
$img->Set(background=>\@rgb);
$img->ReadImage();
```

I've also tried:

```
$img->Colorize(fill=>\@rgb, opacity=>1);
```

Any ideas?

---

Edit:

This worked.  Not sure if there is any cleaner approach:

```
ReadImage("xc:rgb(" . $rgb[0]*100 . "," . $rgb[1]*100 . "," . $rgb[2]*100 . ")")
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
my $rgbdec = $swatchImg->Get("pixel[2,11]");
my @rgbdec = split (/,/, $rgbdec);
my @rgbhex;
## Convert decimal @rgbdec (0..65536) to hex @rgbhex (00..FF)
for (my $i=0; $i<=3; $i++) {
    $rgbhex[$i] = sprintf("%X", $rgbdec[$i]/256); 
    if ($rgbhex[$i] eq "0") { $rgbhex[$i] = "00"; }
}
my $hexcolor = $rgbhex[0].$rgbhex[1].$rgbhex[2];

my $img = Image::Magick->new(size=>"50x50);
$img->Read("xc:#$hexcolor");
```

This assumes you are using ImageMagick with q-depth of 16 bits. If only 8 bits, then this:

```
    $rgbhex[$i] = sprintf("%X", $rgbdec[$i]/256);
```

becomes this:

```
    $rgbhex[$i] = sprintf("%X", $rgbdec[$i]);
```

Although I believe there is a simpler way to just use the decimal values in @rgbdec, perhaps someone will post that.

Comment: It doesn't seem to matter whether I use the hex code or RGB value.  Either one results in a black image.

Comment: Can you print out the value of the items in @rgbdec as well as $hexcolor?

Comment: Your second revision worked!  Although it would be nice to use the RGB values directly.

Comment: Here's some sample rgb values:  0 0.380392156862745 0.666666666666667

Comment: This worked, although not the prettiest solution: ReadImage("xc:rgb(" . $rgb[0]*100 . "%," . $rgb[1]*100 . "%," . $rgb[2]*100 . "%)")

Comment: Ah yes, I had a feeling it was some kind of rgb(a,b,c) ... Thanks!

Comment: Thank you! Your example helped.